# How to calculate Stepping Thread Group result count

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use Stepping Thread Group..but I did nt get how to calculate the http request count.This is my Stepping Thread Group
I got total 3958 result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of http requests sended during the test, you can to add the next listeners: aggregate report or summary report. If you want to control the number of executions in the second - use throughput shaping timer.

Comment: Thank u Jay and Vodevil...I used Summary Report..but I have given 50 thread,but its running more than 50,and how to set the running time..I used same requst in normal jmeter(java request) all results are passed but in stepping thread same results are falied..Iam wondering,any solution for this?or want o add some thing extra(.jar files)

Comment: You can add Listener "view result tree" to the test plan and examine the reason of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [__counter()](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) function to calculate http request count. This function starting with 1 and increasing incrementally by one each time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't predict the exact number of requests for the test that use Stepping Thread Group. The nature of STG is to provide desired test duration time. Thus, the number of requests made during the test will depend on service response times and delay timers you use.

However, you may use counters with If controllers to limit number of requests.